# Using ValueFormatter in MP Chart but it does not taking effect

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart, formatter

Using MP Chart in Android. Reference : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

I have to display **30.8351** as **30.83** on the BAR Chart.

So I found that We can do it with the use of Value Formater in MP Chart.

So I have created class for it as below :

```
class MyValueFormatter : ValueFormatter() {
override fun getFormattedValue(
    value: Float,
    entry: Entry,
    dataSetIndex: Int,
    viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler
): String {
    var mFormat : DecimalFormat=DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0")
    return mFormat.format(value) + " $"
 }
}
```

and then setting this to my chart's dataset as below :

```
val set1: BarDataSet
set1.setValueFormatter(MyValueFormatter())
```

But Still its displaying **30.8351** instead of **30.83** above the Bar Graph i.e. as a value of BAR.

What might be the Issue ?

**EDIT BELOW AFTER JEEL ANSWERED**

I have used Value Formator as below now:

```
set1.valueFormatter= object : ValueFormatter() {
                    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
                        var mFormat : DecimalFormat = DecimalFormat("##.##")
                        return mFormat.format(value)
                    }
                }
```

But for the value **-0.594** I am getting **-0.6**
It should be **-0.59** only.

For **1.234** it's **1.23** (OKAY)

But for **1.235** it's **1.24** (NOT OKAY) - it should not round the value.

What might be the issue ?

Comment: Try with DecimalFormat("#.##")

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `DecimalFormat`. I tried it myself and seems to return the desired result. I'm not familiar with MP Chart but it seems to me it doesn't use the `ValueFormatter`

Comment: @MohitDholakia not working.

Comment: @IvoBeckers not working

Answer (score 4):

According to version 3.1.0 of MPAndroidChart,

The method of [**ValueFormatter**](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/ValueFormatter.html#ValueFormatter--) that you're using is deprecated.

In order to use formatted value, one should either use specific method according to graph type or else use general method [`getFormattedValue(float value)`](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/ValueFormatter.html#getFormattedValue-float-) *(single argument method)*.

---

The method used in the O.P. is deprecated according to the document [here](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/ValueFormatter.html#getFormattedValue-float-com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry-int-com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler-) which might be the reason that formatter isn’t working on the chart.

You should either use [`getBarLable(BarEntry barEntry)`](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/ValueFormatter.html#getBarLabel-com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry-) for the bar chart or else `getFormattedValue(float value)` in general to format the label.

Follow [this document](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/) for more info.

Comment: Edited the Question. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Note : Do not use deprecated method. (As per the above Jeel's Answer.)

It was the issue with Rounding of the Values. Done as below finally :

**df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING**

```
     set1.valueFormatter= object : ValueFormatter() {
     override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
                val df = DecimalFormat("##.##");
                df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
                return df.format(value)
             }
           }
```